# how to dynamically build a function and find root python

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['n','m','value','x'], index = [1,2,3,4])
data['n'] = [3,4,5,2]
data['m'] = [1,2,3,2]
data['value'] = [0.2,0.5,0.3,0.9]
```

I would like to find the root of below equation x and put it in the 'x' column of that dataframe for each row.

[image]

Comment: It's unlikely anyone wants to write you code for you; this is not a free coding service.  You might also want to add the `pandas` tag.

Comment: @TomServo Sorry that was not the intention. I will google more.

Comment: There's a [dozen of ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms) to find the roots of an equation, the simpliest one I would say is [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Is your problem **put it in the 'x' column of that dataframe**?

Comment: @Countour-Integral I am having trouble dynamically building the function. I am still trying to figure out a way.. if I do find I will post!

Comment: @JH Y What do you mean dynamically build the function? Can't you just do `def function(value, x, m, k): return (1 + value * x**m) - (value**2 * sum([x**k for _ in range n]))
`

Comment: @Countour-Integral Sorry I think I can do it! Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

```
def poly_fuction(x, n, m, value):
    return (1+value*x**m) - (value**2*sum([x**_ for _ in range(n+1)]))

from scipy import optimize
sol = optimize.root(function,[0],(2,1,0.1))
# where n = 2, m = 1, value = 0.1
x = sol.x
(1+0.1*x**1) - (0.1**2*(1+x**1+x**2)) # should return a small value close to zero
```